# Do verbs have plural forms?

Tags: verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

According to https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sub-verb.htm

Subjects and verbs must AGREE with one another in number (singular or plural). Thus, if a subject is singular, its verb must also be singular; if a subject is plural, its verb must also be plural.

But what about in the case of singular subject performing a verb multiple times?

is it acceptable to say

for EX. the terrorist demand a million dollars in cash in exchange for the hostage

but wouldn't it be confusing because you're supposed to add an s to the verb following a singular subject so that they agree with each other?

Comment: The sentence is incorrect. It should either be "the terrorists demand" or "the terrorist demands" in accordance with the rule you stated. I don't see where the confusion is, unless you think that adding an 's' to a verb pluralises it (as for a noun).

Comment: Hello mefusen. Your question shows that you haven't understood some basic facts about conjugating verbs. I think this sort of question is much more suited to the English Language Learners site. https://ell.stackexchange.com/  Best wishes!

Answer (score 2):

The question asked: "But what about in the case of singular subject performing a verb multiple times?"

Subject and verb agreement is solely based on whether the subject is singular or plural. It doesn't matter if the subject (whether singular or plural) performs the verb multiple times. You would use an adverb or adverbial phrase to communicate that information.

For example:

- singular, once: "The terrorist demands .."
- singular, multiple times: "The terrorist repeatedly demands ..", "The terrorist demands again and again ..", etc.
- plural, once: "The terrorists demand .."
- plural, multiple times: "The terrorists repeatedly demand ..", "The terrorists demand again and again ..", etc.